# Serializable class not available to broker AMQ

Tags: java, apache-camel, activemq-classic

I'm getting below exception when i try to send object payload message.

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Forbidden class XXXX This class is not trusted to be serialized as ObjectMessage payload. Please take a look at http://activemq.apache.org/objectmessage.html for more information on how to configure trusted classes.
at org.apache.activemq.util.ClassLoadingAwareObjectInputStream.checkSecurity(ClassLoadingAwareObjectInputStream.java:112)
at org.apache.activemq.util.ClassLoadingAwareObjectInputStream.resolveClass(ClassLoadingAwareObjectInputStream.java:57)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1922)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1805)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2096)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1624)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:464)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:422)
at org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQObjectMessage.getObject(ActiveMQObjectMessage.java:211)
... 21 common frames omitted
```

Checked the given url.

1. Set the jar in bin and given the classpath in wrapper.conf
2. Set the trustAllpackages to true in client
3. Set -Dorg.apache.activemq.SERIALIZABLE_PACKAGES=* in amq broker activemq.bat

what else needed?

Comment: Where is the error being generated, client or broker?  Also provide broker version info in your questions so folks know what you are using

Comment: Error is in client.Using latest amq

Comment: Probably the `trustAllpackages` on the client is not working. Would you mind posting your config where you set this? And your object class is serializable, isn't it?